# Load png from URL save it and display it

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex3, flex4.5

I'm new to Flash Builder 4.6 and trying to make a mobile application.
I'm trying to load a png file from a website and then save it with PersistenceManager for later display. But nothing shows.
Here is how I load the image, looks like it is working.

```
    public class MySetup
{
    public var myId:String;
    public var myName:String;
    public var myImage:Object;
}
   protected function loadImage():void{
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest ("http://www.myweb.com/pictures/myImage.png");
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
    loader.load(request);
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, oncomplete);
    }

    protected function oncomplete(e:Event):void{ 
var saveManager:PersistenceManager = new PersistenceManager();
var loader2:URLLoader = e.target as URLLoader; 
if (loader2 != null){ 
        mySetup.myLogo = loader2.data;

        } 
        else{ 
            trace("an error has occured!"); 
        } 
        mySetup.myId = myId.text;
        mySetup.myName = myName.text;
        saveManager.setProperty("setupData", mySetup);
        saveManager.save();

        }
```

Now I try to display the image, then I get an error:

```
    private var myLogo:Image;
    protected function view1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
    {
    var loadManager:PersistenceManager = new PersistenceManager();
    if(loadManager.load())
        {
        var savedData:Object = loadManager.getProperty("setupData");    
            if(savedData){
                        myLogo = savedData.myLogo;
                        }
         }
     }


     <s:Image id="MyImage" y="10" width="290" height="164" scaleMode="stretch" source="myLogo"/>
```

Thanks for any help.
Kim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

myLogo have to be a ByteArray.